# Arrayformula - Cell contains text (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, contains, array-formulas

I have the formula written below. On the condition where Column E = "EPIs", there is a second condition to verify if Column G contains the string ("CC", "Hemo" or "odonto").

But that second condition is not returning correctly the 'contains the specified string' part.
It gets true for Col E = "EPIs", but false for the second cases.

How can I make it work?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(B3:B="";"";
IF(M3:M="";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Realizado - Sem Certificado";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Manutenção";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Verificar";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Verificar se está ativo";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Não realizado";"Verificar";
IF(M3:M="Desativado";"DESATIVADO";

IF(E3:E="EPIs";
(IF(G3:G="*CC*";IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M);MONTH(M3:M)+6;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M);MONTH(M3:M)+4;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido"); 
IF(G3:G="*hemo*";IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M);MONTH(M3:M)+6;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M);MONTH(M3:M)+4;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido");
IF(G3:G="*odonto*";IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+2;MONTH(M3:M);DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+2;MONTH(M3:M)-2;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido"); 
IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+1;MONTH(M3:M);DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+1;MONTH(M3:M)-2;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido")
        ))));

IF(E3:E="Odonto Intra";IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+2;MONTH(M3:M);DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+2;MONTH(M3:M)-2;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido");
IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+1;MONTH(M3:M);DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();IF(DATE(YEAR(M3:M)+1;MONTH(M3:M)-2;DAY(M3:M))>TODAY();"OK";"Realizar CQ");"Vencido") ) ))))))))))
```

Comment: Have you researched the VLOOKUP function?

Comment: I guess VLOOKUP wouldn't work for ARRAYFORMULA, because it would always return the first value, and all the data below it would return true (which wouldn't be correct).

(That is just a guess. Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Maybe you could make a copy then share it as an editable link and we can help?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OYaFrvsarhCLjOOptevh_x1fsNI7WG6LVYy1sujUp58/edit?usp=sharing

The formula is on P3. I guess the best case to experiment would be "CC".

Comment: @MattKing It is editable now

Comment: take a look at the MK.Help tab.  could you put the correct desired results MANUALLY in Column R??  1500 rows seems a bit much so maybe just delete a bunch of rows so that theres a representative sample of all/many the possible outcomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you wrote is quite a bit more convoluted than you needed it to be.

I think using EDATE() and LOOKUP() you can achieve the desired effect more easily.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(M3:M="";;LOOKUP(TODAY()-EDATE(M3:M;IF(REGEXMATCH(G3:G;"Hemo|CC");6;IF(REGEXMATCH(G3:G;"Odonto");24;12)));{-9^9;-60;0};{"OK";"Realizar";"Vencido"})))
```